# Should I call or talk directly?

Tags: management, communication

In my office (i mean it's not mine) has a telephone where connect my room and my boss room, I want to talk something to her, Should I call or go to her room and talk directly?

Comment: Are you asking if you should call your boss or speak to her face to face when you have a question?  Without any additional information I would have to say "Yes".  Phone call vs walk to her office depends on the office culture and what you need to speak about.  Providing more information may give us the opportunity to give a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Face to face is usually best. There's much more nuances to a conversation in person. Just don't waste her time with inconsequentials.

If it's urgent and very minor I would ring rather than waste time if I just needed a quick yes/no answer authorising me to do something or a similar reason and her office was not within a few minutes walk.